# Как настроить агрегацию данных в Graphite?

Tags: linux, администрирование, мониторинг, аналитика

Приветствую всех. Стоит задача прилепить мониторинг к одному приложению. Есть штука, которая шлёт метрики, с этим все хорошо.
Но есть параметр, который необходимо хранить не так, как все остальное. А именно: количество запросов. Т.е. прилетает запрос, обрабатывается и в Graphite отправляются следующие метрики:
1) время, потраченное на внешний запрос;
2) время работы приложения
3) сам факт запуска приложения

Мне в этом Graphite нужно каким-то макаром посчитать количество этих запусков. Я уже и schemas настроил и aggregation тоже, но блин какого черта он не может мне сделать то, что я от него хочу?
Сам факт запуска фиксируется так: отсылается просто единица в опр. метрику и все. Мне потом допустим нужно посчитать количество этих единиц каждый час и выводить это на графике, но он разумеется не выводит.

storage-schemas.conf

```
# Schema definitions for Whisper files. Entries are scanned in order,
# and first match wins. This file is scanned for changes every 60 seconds.
#
#  [name]
#  pattern = regex
#  retentions = timePerPoint:timeToStore, timePerPoint:timeToStore, ...

# Carbon's internal metrics. This entry should match what is specified in
# CARBON_METRIC_PREFIX and CARBON_METRIC_INTERVAL settings
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[app]
pattern = ^app\.api\.*
retentions = 10s:10m,10m:30d,60m:1y
```

storage-aggregation.conf

```
[collectd]
pattern = ^collectd\.
xFilesFactor = 0.7
aggregationMethod = max

[count]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[default]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.5
aggregationMethod = average
```

Как мне настроить его или же какие функции применить к метрике уже на графике, чтобы он посчитал количество этих единичек за опр. период времени (это зависит от масштаба графика и никак в конфигах или где бы то ни было еще не должно указываться)?
Функции, которые я применяю к этой метрике выдают полный бред. Тот же countSeries, sumSeries, hitcount и т.д.

Вообще я удивлен. Так мало информации про этот Graphite. Везде пишут, что он такой весь масштабируемый и простой, что вот прям бери и радуйся. Везде пишут про его настройку в разных стеках и окружениях, НО никто не описывает как решаются те или иные проблемы, нет никаких примеров. В общем прошу помочь, у меня уж очень сильно от него пригорело за последние дни, т.к. не могу я при помощи него решить такую простую задачу.